Simplicial complexes for measuring semantics of concepcts from natural languages?
In a nice paper describing some of the encodings of the semantics in large language models, simplices occur:
Here is a quote from their abstract:
"We find a remarkably simple structure: simple categorical concepts are represented as simplices, hierarchically related concepts are orthogonal in a sense we make precise, and (in consequence) complex concepts are represented as polytopes constructed from direct sums of simplices, reflecting the hierarchical structure."
Here is an image illustrating this quote from their paper:

I asked a similar question a few weeks earlier which I deleted, but now when coming back to read this paper it occured to me that one could use the language / tools of algebraic topology such as simplicial complexes and homology to compare / measure the meaning/semantic of "real world" objects such as natural language maybe for explicitly reasoning in artificial intelligence about "complex concepts".
For instance the first Betti number of a "complex concepts" would be the number of the connected components of the simplicial complex. One could imagine using SageMath and a vocabulary of words, that one constructs a toy database of words and corresponding Euler Characterstics, Betti numbers and other topological invariants associated to the simplicial complex of the word / complex concept one is currently investigating.
I guess my question is in the first place:

Given a word such as "Elephant" and maybe a graph of words or the Wordnet vocabulary. How do the authors of the paper extract the simplicial complex which they call "polytopes constructed from direct sums of simplices"?

If the image happens to be intuitive in meaning for you: How would you define a toy model consisting of another "complex concept" or just "concept" and the simplicial complex with defines this "complex concept"/"concept" using mathematical notation?


I record here two more questions but my interest is more in the first and second question meant to be given as a full answer, while I would be happy for the next two questions if they are commented on:

What other mathematical tools from algebraic topology or any other area which uses simplicial complexes might be useful to look into in this situation?

Is Topological Data Analaysis such an area and does it have mature python libraries which could be used outside academia?


